# In ARIMA what values can p, d, q have?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

In the arima function in R what values can be assigned to `p`, `d`, `q` , because for some reason in every example that I see out there [(like this one)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3) tests values of 0 and 1 to get optimal model, but can't I test with values like 2, 4, 5?.

I don't mind leaving the computer for several hours executing the process, but I want to get the best model.

Comment: In general, ARIMA($p,d,q$) models are defined for $p,q,d \in \mathbb{N}$. It is also unclear what tests you want to conduct exactly.

Comment: @JeremiasK I'm just following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3) tutorial and I want to know if I can get better results if I use `p = d = q = range(0, 10)` instead of `p = d = q = range(0, 2)`